# Windows 10 pc doesn't wake to run scheduled task that's set to "Wake this computer to run this task."

Tags: windows, sleep, scheduled-tasks, timer

**I wrote brieflySleep.bat to put the pc to sleep for 10 seconds**, in order to power-cycle my ssd. (More about the purpose below, in case someone is curious.)  brieflySleep executes the "SCHTASKS /change" command to schedule an existing task that has its "Wake the computer to run this task" condition enabled, then waits until  10 seconds before the scheduled wakeup time, and then executes "psshutdown -d -t 0" to immediately put the pc to sleep.  **The pc goes to sleep, but fails to wake**.

The SCHTASKS /change command displays a "success" message.  The scheduled task executes after I *manually* wake the pc. (But I don't want to have to wake the pc manually. My eventual goal is to schedule brieflySleep to run automatically at night, once every few days.)  The scheduled task will execute at the correct time if I modify brieflySleep so it skips the psshutdown command, but that defeats the purpose of brieflySleep.

Wake Timers are enabled in the active power plan.  Hibernation and hybrid sleep are disabled in the power plan, and Fast Startup is unchecked in the power settings.  The BIOS is configured to enable the OS to control wake events. (That assumes I didn't overlook some other necessary BIOS setting. Motherboard is MSI X470 Gaming Plus, BIOS is American Megatrends version A.B0 dated 2019/07/04.)

**Are there any relevant settings that I've overlooked?**

The same problem occurs using Gibson Research's wizmo.exe instead of psshutdown.

I'm wondering whether Windows Task Scheduler might need more time after SCHTASKS "successfully" executes, to actually update the motherboard's RTC with the newly scheduled time.  brieflySleep runs the SCHTASK command about 20 seconds before it puts the pc to sleep, and maybe 20 seconds isn't enough time for Windows to get around to updating the RTC.

**UPDATE 2020-11-14:** I did two experiments: (1) I tested whether allowing Windows more time to program the RTC makes a difference, and found that 20 minutes didn't help.  (2) I manually set the wakeup task's scheduled time using Windows Task Scheduler (instead of having brieflySleep set the scheduled time using the "schtasks /change" command) and that worked okay: the pc woke at the scheduled time.  **Experiment 2 proves wake timers work okay and the BIOS is set okay**.  **The problem seems to be that the SCHTASKS command fails to cause the motherboard's RTC to be updated**... as if SCHTASKS ignores the fact that the task's "Wake the computer to run this task" condition is set. **[End of 2020-11-14 update]**

**UPDATE 2020-11-15:** Some googling led me to a page ( https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html ) that says the SCHTASKS command is inadequate for properties like "Wake the computer to run this task" and that PowerShell is adequate.  The needed PowerShell code appears to be something like:

```
$Taskname = <arg1>
$Time = <arg2>
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -WakeToRun
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $Time -Once
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Taskname -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
```

I haven't yet tested whether that will successfully wake the pc, but it at least updates the task's properties in Windows Task Scheduler, and I'm optimistic.  Assuming it will work, I still need to learn how to get brieflySleep to run PowerShell code.  Two approaches I found by googling are to put the PowerShell code into a .ps1 script file ( https://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/ ) and launch the .ps1 from the .bat, or embed the PowerShell code inside the .bat file ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-windows-batch-file ).  The latter seems appropriate for a tiny amount of simple PowerShell code. **[End of 2020-11-15 update]**

Here's brieflySleep.bat :

```
@echo off
rem  Must be "run as Administrator" else the SCHTASKS command will fail.
rem  For Notes and Changelog, see bottom.

rem  If command line parameter is DEBUG, the pc will not be put to sleep and
rem     the wakeup task will be a task that does not launch an ssd selftest.
if [%1]==[DEBUG] (
   set "_DEBUG=TRUE"
) else (
   set "_DEBUG=FALSE"
)

rem ------------------------------------------------------------------
rem  EDIT THESE CONSTANTS IF NECESSARY TO CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR SYSTEM.
call %~dp0%setCONSTANTS.bat
set /A "SLEEPSECS=10"
set "SLEEPPROG=%PROGDIR%\psshutdown.exe"
set "SLEEPCMD=%SLEEPPROG% -d -t 0 -e p:22:22"
rem set "SLEEPPROG=%PROGDIR%\wizmo.exe"
rem set "SLEEPCMD=%SLEEPPROG% standby"
set "WAKETASK=\Fix_SSD\Wake and launch ssd selftest"
if %_DEBUG%==TRUE   set "WAKETASK=\Fix_SSD\Wake and launch cmd"
rem ------------------------------------------------------------------

echo    Debug parameter: %_DEBUG%
echo    WakeTask: "%WAKETASK%"
echo    Sleep duration: %SLEEPSECS% seconds
echo    Sleep command: "%SLEEPCMD%"
echo    ____

cd %PROGDIR%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem  Verify existence of utility used to put pc to sleep:
if not exist %SLEEPPROG% (
   echo Missing utility "%SLEEPPROG%" which is needed to put pc to sleep.
   echo Aborting.
   pause
   EXIT /B
)
rem  Verify existence of task needed to wake pc:
schtasks /query /tn "%WAKETASK%" >NUL 2>&1
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
   echo Missing task "%WAKETASK%" which is needed to wake pc.
   echo Aborting.
   pause
   EXIT /B
)

rem  Calculate the time of day hh:mm to wake the pc.  Because it can't
rem     be hh:mm:ss, and because the desired amount of sleep is 10 seconds,
rem     this .bat will delay up to a minute or two before putting the 
rem     pc to sleep, so that the pc can be put to sleep for 10 seconds.
rem  To calculate hh:mm we first need to get the current time:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("!time!") do (
   set /A "_HH=%%a, _MM=1%%b-100, _SS=1%%c-100"
)
rem  If current time is nearly some hh:mm:00, wait until after hh:mm before proceeding,
rem     to ensure enough time remains in the minute to schedule the wakeup task and
rem     to sleep %SLEEPSECS% seconds:
set /A "_SecsToMin=60-_SS"
set /A "_Margin=30+SLEEPSECS"
if !_SecsToMin! LEQ !_Margin!  (
   set /A "SecsToWait=1+_SecsToMin"
   echo    !date! !time!  Waiting !SecsToWait! seconds until the next minute...
   TIMEOUT /t !SecsToWait! >nul
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("!time!") do (
      set /A "_HH=%%a, _MM=1%%b-100, _SS=1%%c-100"
)  )
rem  If current time is nearly some hh:00:00, wait until after hh:00 before proceeding,
rem      to avoid timing error that would be caused by a a midnight rollover or
rem      by a daylight savings time change:
set /A "_SecsToHour=3600-(60*_MM+_SS)"
set /A "_Margin=60+_Margin"
if !_SecsToHour! LEQ !_Margin!  (
   set /A "SecsToWait=1+_SecsToHour"
   echo    !date! !time!  Waiting !SecsToWait! seconds until the next hour...
   TIMEOUT /t !SecsToWait! >nul
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("!time!") do (
      set /A "_HH=%%a, _MM=1%%b-100, _SS=1%%c-100"
)  )
set "MMDDYYYY=!date:~4,2!/!date:~7,2!/!date:~10,4!!"
set "_HHnow=0!_HH!"
set "_MMnow=0!_MM!"
rem  Calculate when the next minute will start:
set /A "_MM=_MM+1"
if !_MM! GEQ 60   set /A "_MM=0, _HH=_HH+1"
rem  Since the schtasks command expects time in the format hh:mm, ensure hours
rem      and minutes are each two digits by prepending a leading zero if necessary:
set "_HH=0!_HH!"
set "_MM=0!_MM!"
set "HHMM=!_HH:~-2!:!_MM:~-2!"
echo    !date! !time!  Scheduling "%WAKETASK%" to run at !HHMM!:00
SCHTASKS /change /tn "%WAKETASK%" /ru SYSTEM /rp "" /sd %MMDDYYYY% /st %HHMM%
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
   echo SCHTASKS returned an errorlevel that was not 0.  Aborting.
   pause
   EXIT /B
) else (
   echo    The wakeup task has been scheduled to run at !HHMM!:00.
)

rem  Wait until SLEEPSECS seconds before the scheduled wake time, then put the pc to sleep:
set /A "_SleepSS=60-SLEEPSECS"
set /A "SecsToWait=_SleepSS-_SS"
set "_SleepSS=0!_SleepSS!"
echo    !date! !time!  Waiting !SecsToWait! seconds until !_HHnow:~-2!:!_MMnow:~-2!:!_SleepSS:~-2! before putting pc to sleep...
TIMEOUT /T !SecsToWait! >nul
if !_DEBUG!==TRUE (
   echo    !date! !time!  Since command-line parameter is DEBUG, skipping the sleep.
) else (
   echo    !date! !time!  Putting pc to sleep now using command "%SLEEPCMD%"...
   %SLEEPCMD%
)
EXIT /B

------------------------
NOTES
   This .bat will put the pc to sleep for about 10 seconds, in order to power 
cycle the ssd, to mitigate the Crucial ssd's excessive write amplification 
that gets worse the longer the ssd has been powered up.
   This .bat relies on the existence of a task in Windows Task Scheduler 
that will wake the pc.  This .bat uses the SCHTASKS command to schedule that 
task to run 10 seconds after this .bat puts the pc to sleep.  That task 
merely launches an ssd selftest, because power cycling the ssd apparently 
aborts a selftest that may have been in progress.
   This .bat must be run as Administrator, else the SCHTASKS command will fail.
   Assumptions: (1) The wakeup task's property "Wake the pc to run this task" 
is set.  (2) "Wake Timers" are enabled in the Power Plan.  (3) The pc BIOS is 
set to let the OS manage the motherboard's RTC (real time clock) wakeup alarm.  
   This .bat relies on Microsoft's free PSSHUTDOWN.exe utility.
   A future version of this .bat may arrange for the brief sleep to happen 
in the middle of the night.

CHANGELOG
Initial version, so no changes yet.
```

Here's why I want to occasionally power-cycle the ssd:  Crucial MX500 ssds apparently have a bug that causes excessive write amplification, which isn't as extreme during the first few days after the ssd is power-cycled.  The bug isn't well known, but on my ssd it correlates perfectly with the well known "Bogus Current Pending Sectors" bug, and the perfect correlation is a hint that most people with MX500 ssds have excessive write amplification but aren't aware of it.  Two reasons why people won't be aware of it are: (1) their computers write much more to their ssds than my computer does, so their excess write amplification is not as huge compared to their necessary write amplification, and (2) some people shut off or sleep their computers frequently (unlike my computer which runs 24 hours a day) and their power-cycling helps.

(Another thing I do to mitigate the write amplification bug is run ssd selftests nearly nonstop.  Apparently the ssd internal process responsible for the occasional large write bursts is lower priority than a selftest, because the write bursts do not happen while a selftest is running.)

Comment: "maybe 20 seconds isn't enough time for Windows to get around to updating the RTC." have you tried a longer time than 20s?

Comment: I plan to try a time much longer than 20 seconds -- 20 minutes, perhaps -- the next time the write amplification grows large. (Probably in a few days.)  I'll post the result here.  Meanwhile, I'm hoping someone has another suggestion, since my hunch is that that experiment is unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the original post to show the results of two experiments, one of which showed that 20 minutes didn't make a difference.